Text composable wrapContentSize
I'm trying to achieve this text composable with subscript... such that for shorter text ..it'll wrap the view, otherwise it'll take the whole spacelike image 1

And I tried using buildAnotatedString to create a subscript
But I keep getting image 2 as result

I also tried using a row
Text -> fillmaxwidth(0.9f)

Subscript is left with the remaining space
But that won't make the composable wrap content size for shorter text
